# Simple NFC Code not working?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am trying to find a start writing an app using NFC. I simply need to send a NDef Message from one phone to another containing only a simple String.

My transmit Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(
                new NdefRecord[] { createTextRecord("Bla", Locale.GERMANY , true )});
        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(msg, this);
    }



    public NdefRecord createTextRecord(String payload, Locale locale, boolean encodeInUtf8) {
        byte[] langBytes = locale.getLanguage().getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        Charset utfEncoding = encodeInUtf8 ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : Charset.forName("UTF-16");
        byte[] textBytes = payload.getBytes(utfEncoding);
        int utfBit = encodeInUtf8 ? 0 : (1 << 7);
        char status = (char) (utfBit + langBytes.length);
        byte[] data = new byte[1 + langBytes.length + textBytes.length];
        data[0] = (byte) status;
        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, data, 1, langBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, data, 1 + langBytes.length, textBytes.length);
        NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
        NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], data);
        return record;
    }
   }
```

Then I simply try to receive some Intent on the other phone that something happend:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Received an Event onResume", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

}
```

Sadly nothing happens if I tap the phones. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @ArtooDetoo Lol what ? :D

Comment: @Little Child: I'm joking... ;)

Answer (score 2):

[On Their website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html). You should always look up in the documentation first.

> This document describes the basic NFC tasks you perform in Android. It
>   explains how to send and receive NFC data in the form of NDEF messages
>   and describes the Android framework APIs that support these features.
>   For more advanced topics, including a discussion of working with
>   non-NDEF data, see Advanced NFC.

Comment: Yes of course I looked at the site and used it, yet I cannot get the example up and working. There is no Demo Code that seems to function correctly online anywhere.